# Unique constraint violated while insert

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I'm running this code

```
INSERT INTO ADW12_DW.WC_MFG SELECT * FROM ADW12_DW.WC_MFG_bkp;
COMMIT;
```

Prior to this, ADW12_DW.WC_MFG was truncated to update column size. So ADW12_DW.WC_MFG is empty before running the above code.

Comment: Seems like ADW12_DW.WC_MFG_bkp contains duplicates not allowed in ADW12_DW.WC_MFG.

Comment: The error message should contain the name of the actual constraint being violated. Check which one it is and verify if you have a similar one on the other table.

Comment: I would check the column update script. It seems they added a unique constraint as well, and your backup has violated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be duplicates in the data being added.  Here is one way to limit the insert data:

```
INSERT INTO ADW12_DW.WC_MFG
    SELECT w.*
    FROM ADW12_DW.WC_MFG_bkp w
    WHERE w.rowid IN (SELECT MIN(w2.rowid)
                      FROM ADW12_DW.WC_MFG_bkp w2
                      WHERE w2.col = w.col
                     );
```

`col` represents what is "unique".  It may be more than one column.